# How can a C program be used in Android to serve API from 127.0.0.1?

Tags: android, c, cordova

I know an open source project coded in C, which compiles as system executable for Linux, Windows, OS X, iOS and Android.

On Linux/Windows/OSX it can be just executed with `./example_programm` or `C:\>exeample_program.exe` and it starts serving it's API through http://127.0.0.1:port_number, example: http://127.0.0.1:7778

on Desktop platforms this API can be used by GUI application.

I need to know how this can be done on Android ?

I know on Android `adb shell` we can do `su` and then run android compiled program executable, and then probably use open the HTML GUI from android web browser and use it. But, this shouldn't be the case I guess.

The executable doesn't need ANY root or superuser privileges. a limited user account if run the executable makes this executable run and the program starts serving API on `127.0.0.1`.

As and alternative I heard Android can either use Cordova wrapper to include this android compiled executable in it and when the Android App starts the App can trigger to execute this android executable in backend. But, I'm not so sure at the moment, if that way will work or not, or what challenges will there be. This probably needs to be tested.

Another alternate way I heard is to have this C code compiled as a library. I have no idea of C coding done in this project, and I don't know what changes I need to make to compile it as Android library. Anyway if with some help I could have this C code compiled for Android as a library, can someone please let me know how this library can be called by the Android App, and it will behave exactly the same ways it behaves on Desktop platform ? like executing the executable and it starts serving API on 127.0.0.1:7778 ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: "I have no idea of C coding" - So learning the language first is mandatory if you want to write/port a C program. Get a beginner's C book, learn the basics, to some simple excercises without networking first. Then learn how networking is done on Linux. And after you know all this, learn the differences on Android.

Comment: From project management point of view, I don't necessarily need to learn C. I just need to understand the possibilities and hire the devs.

Comment: @satinder you're totally wrong, if its not your job or responsibilities of technical things, so leave it to developers.
if its your responsibility, so you have to moderate knowledge of things

Comment: @satinder: This attittude is a good way to crash the project. I've seen enough project manager who don't know about the things they nevertheless wanted to decide. This aggravates and frustrates the devs who have to justify things obvious for every developer. As an occasional project manager myself, I strongly recommend to reconsider your position.

Comment: none of you have given me any related answer. I'll be waiting for some answers related to the original question.

Comment: `serving it's API through http://127.0.0.1:port_number`. So the web server will only be used by apps running on the same device as the web server? Why this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, you can use the Android NDK to run C or C++ code in an Android application: https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

Whether or not *"it will behave exactly the same ways it behaves on Desktop platform"* is unknown because I don't know any details about this library. If it's a simple web service, it's likely that it will work.

Regarding making design decisions, I'd leave that alone and just go in with the knowledge that C code can run on Android, then have someone familiar with Android and/or the NDK determine the best way to use the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The C program is an open source code available on github, which can act as like a lite bitcoin wallet. without needing to download blockchain database. I see Electrum and such wallets are already supported on Android, so I know it must be possible to use it on Android for sure. It's a fairly complex C code, and that's why I can not say what changes needs to be done in it. And that's why I wanted some expert's suggestion before I ask some expert dev to make it work on Android. https://github.com/jl777/SuperNET

Comment: Not familiar with the library, but there is a commit addressing Android with compilation instructions: https://github.com/jl777/SuperNET/commit/71f6ebdf237d8c4018c067c8bed90de6c7f542a6

Comment: Yes, that's my documentation on how to compile it for android. I made it to compile for android, but later I felt stuck on how to include it in an Android App.

Comment: That's where the NDK comes in. It will allow you to call C functions from Java code.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher :)